# Geometric Inequality problem

Tags: contest-math

Within a problem I was solving I came across

Prove $xy+yz+xz \geq 2xyz$ for all non-negative real numbers $x,y,z$.

I have attempted to prove this for some time now, but cannot find a solution that works. The closest I came was trying the AM GM inequality with xy, yz, and xz as my 3 terms, but obviously we need 2 terms.

Comment: $x, y, z$ integers?

Comment: @Soham real numbers

Comment: positive real numbers?

Comment: positive real numbers,

Comment: Have you considered $x=y=z$ ? you get something slightly dubious. There's probably another condition

Comment: well these are just the segments formed by the tangents of the inscribed circle in a triangle if that helps

Comment: Well, for $x=y=z=2$ we have $4+4+4=12<16=2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2$.

Answer (score 1):

> Prove \begin{align}xy+yz+xz \ge 2xyz \tag{1}\label{1}\end{align} for all non-negative real numbers $x,y,z$.

A primitive counterexample:
for non-negative real numbers $x=y=z=2$
we have
\begin{align} 
4+4+4&=12<16=2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2
,
\end{align}
so the statement \eqref{1} is obviously false.